# Why does scipy.odeint with differing step size in the t array gives qualitatively different results?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint, strange-attractor

I am investigating strange attractors and am currently working on the Duffing attractor (a 2D strange attractor).  The solution trajectory makes loops in the positive and negative x direction and I am particularly interested in the sequence in which it switches back and forth between the two (the pattern is chaotic).  This is fairly easy to assess since you can plot the x-value of the trajectory vs. time (the independent variable).  I use the following code:

```
a=0.35
b=0.3
w=1

def dX_dt(X, t):
    return np.array([X[1],
                     X[0]-(X[0]**3)-a*X[1]+b*np.cos(w*t)])

tstepmax=5000
tmax=1000
tmin=0
t1 = np.linspace(tmin, tmax+tmin,  tstepmax)
X1=odeint(dX_dt,[0,0],t1)
```

I was not sure how many steps were required for a given number of time-units, so I experimented with setting `tstepmax` to 50000 and 500000.  To my surprise, after a fairly short time these gave qualitatively different results as seen in this plot image:
[Three overlaid trajectories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uzEU.jpg)
I was under the impression that the `t1` vector was simply where the trajectory was evaluated for plotting purposes and that the method internally determined the step size to use; indeed, for some methods the step size isn't constant over the trajectory.  However, this change gives a fundamentally different trajectory.  Why? And, perhaps more importantly, which is the "real" trajectory?  How can I reliably obtain the "real" trajectory?

Comment: You mean the attractor to the ODE of George Duffing (1861–1944)? Could you also compare the solutions in a phase portrait?

Comment: You might be thinking of the Dunning-Krüger effect (denying the existence of unknown unknowns or so)?

Comment: In order to achieve better convergence, you might want to set `rtol=1e-20` or something like that. However, it is a chaotic system, getting the "real" trajectory for long times is going to be hard, because numerical errors, however small, are going to mess things up. Nevertheless, it does seem that your solutions arrive at something at least reminiscent of the Duffing attractor. On this note, you might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowing_lemma) interesting.

Comment: @DiegoFPradilla : One should not demand the physically impossible. The lower bound for the relative tolerance is `1e-14`. This also does not change the principal problem that the solutions diverge qualitatively from each other in the time span of about `150<t<200`

Comment: @LutzLehmann Apologies, I was not aware of that lower bound. However, I ran the code in my machine looping over `rtol` from `1e-10` to `1e-22`, with the same number of time steps, and got different results for each tolerance. Would I not expect the same result if `rtol` were bounded? My other point was that in order to study the Duffing attractor, one might not need the exact time evolution, which is why I posted a suggestion in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @DiegoFPradilla : I would expect an error message, but that might have been with another solver. The `double` or `float64` format has only relative precision down to `mu=2e-16`, the step updates involving many operations this has to be increased somewhat. It depend of course on how the local error estimate or guidance is computed, with extrapolation methods `mu*h` might occur as smallest non-zero error guesstimate, I'm not sure how that works with AB-AM and BDF methods.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was observed and discussed in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42613/need-help-to-fully-understand-scipys-odeints-reported-step-sizes-eval-times.

In short, the cause seems to be that the odeint stepper call (in the lsoda Fortran code) does not go a full step but only to the next output value. The stepper state is saved in a workspace array, but apparently not completely. Some control variables seem to be reset at each call, each call virtually constructs a new stepper object mixing old and default information. This leads to slightly different internal step sequences, thus to slightly different error evolutions, which in a chaotic system can lead to visibly diverging solutions.

Using `solve_ivp` you should not observe this problem, as the time loop there does full internal steps and then interpolates all relevant output values for the current interval. The stepper class continues to exist with all internal information. Thus the internal step sequence should be independent of the `t_eval` argument.

Comment: I had originally avoided solve_ivp because of another stackoverflow discussion in which it was revealed that event reporting did not yet work as advertised; however, I didn't end up using event reporting, so solve_ivp should work fine.  Is there anything special I need to do since the system is nonautonomous? I couldn't find a nonautonomous example of using solve_ivp...

Comment: You only need to take care about the argument order. The step size regulator is a bit more conservative, which shows when computing the examples for the Radau method in the Hairer book. The order mismatch in LSODA which led to the event problem there is afaik repaired since some time. It is in general slower than odeint, this could perhaps be repaired using a custom time loop using the stepper classes.

Comment: That has fixed the problem.  Thank you very much.